# Set page title and project header separate

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I've been messing around with Github Pages and I was wondering if there any way to set the `<title>` tag and the project header title separate?

I want to set the project header to an image but when I set the `title` attribute in the `_config.yml` file the project header is an image as expected but now the site's title is the `<img>` tag as a string literal.

Any way to separate them?

Comment: Which theme are you using

Comment: @marcanuy I'm using the Cayman theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<title>` tag content is controlled by whatever liquid tags are set in the `_layouts` directory. So you could define it in your layouts file(s) to use a different attribute, or go as far as hardcoding a value there.

**Example:**

If you have a `_layouts\default.html` file with a line that says:

```
<title>{{ page.title }}</title>
```

...you could edit that to a different value and it will be used for the `<title>`